# Setup project Visual Studio and Nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have an old legacy project with a Setup for an application. That application is growing and now we are using some Nuget packages inside it, like Owin, or Newtonsoft JSON serializer.

Everything is working fine, our problem is to generate the Setup. It's and old fashioned Setup for VS2010 that is deprecated, so I suppose that I don't have any kind of support with nuget packages. What would you recommend me? Move to a newer installer try to download my packages from Nuget and add them manually to my setup project?

This Setup project is still maintained because it's a big application and migrate it to a new one require some considerable effort.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download and use the

- [Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)

extensions to have support for those legacy setup projects. I still have a solution using the 2015 extension without any glitch.

Comment: And what should I do with the nuget packages inside my project? Must I add them into my setup project or with that extension are automatically added?

Comment: I didn't had to worry about the NuGet packages, because I have added `Content files` and `Primary output` of my main (MVC) project to the setup project and then it takes care of the rest.

Comment: So is a good practice to add my packages folder to the setup and everything will be installed easily? Thank you for your time :)